# Why is libyaml in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server not being patched for security issues?

Tags: 10.04, lts, patch

I'm running a **10.04 LTS server** and [the LTS wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) shows it as being supported until 2015.

However, on [the CVE page for a security vulnerability in libyaml](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2013/CVE-2013-6393.html), the table states:

> Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx): ignored (reached end-of-life)

Why is there a discrepancy here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Desktop has reached EOL, while 10.04 LTS Server is still supported. 10.04 was the last LTS release which had different support length for the Desktop and Server versions. Since 12.04 every LTS release is supported for 5 years.

So the interesting question is what packages have became unsupported by the EOL of 10.04 LTS Desktop? You can look [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseManifest) where you will find a link to [this list](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/ubuntu-cve-tracker/master/view/head:/lucid-supported.txt) of still supported packages. As that list's first line confirms:

> Lucid source packages not in this list are unsupported starting Apr 29, 2013

`libyaml` is not in that list. (How that list was decided I don't know.)

I feel too the discrepancy when it is said that the LTS Server is still supported, but only a few packages are truly supported. But this was well-known before, that the EOL of the Desktop release will cause a lot of packages to be no more supported. This discrepancy is likely one of the cause why Canonical switched to support every LTS release for 5 years, be it Desktop or Server.

Answer (score 1):

Not all packages are supported full time for LTSs. The full support lasts for 24 months. Most desktop pakages are supported for 36 months. After that, only a small subset of packages are maintained because not everyone works for supporting older LTSs. See http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/ubuntu-cve-tracker/master/view/head:/lucid-supported.txt